# __property to property

Tags: c++-cli, managed-c++

I am converting a project from /oldsyntax to /clr and have problems to convert my properties in the public __gc class Reader which has now become public ref class Reader

I have these properties (amongst others) in the .h file

```
__property void set_Xml(System::String *value);
__property System::String *get_Xml();
```

and then in the .cpp file I have

```
void Reader::set_Xml(System::String *value)
{
    if(value->Chars[0] == '<'){
        reader->put_xml(stlString(value).c_str());
    }
    else {
        reader->put_xml_file(stlString(value).c_str());
    }
}

System::String *Reader::get_Xml()
{
    return gcString(reader->get_xml(), reader->state.is_utf8);
}
```

How do I rewrite this so that it can compile with /clr. I am using Visual Studio 2010 ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235304.aspx

Comment: I also looked at this link before, but it does not match my case. I will try to just remove the __property and just keep get_Xml and set_Xml as ordinary methods.

Comment: You also need to replace `*` with `^` for managed classes

Comment: I have rewritten them as :void set_Xml(System::String^ value); and System::String^ get_Xml();

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235304.aspx) posted in the comments has all the information on the new syntax for properties.

- Old: Declare methods with a specific naming convention, decorate them with `__property`.
- New: Declare a property block within your class, and have methods with an additional level of scope. <sub>(Note: I'm not sure if "additional level of scope" is the proper way to describe it, see below.)</sub>

For a property named `Xml` of type `String`, the syntax would be:

In the header file:

```
public ref class Reader
{
public:
    property String^ Xml
    {  
        String^ get();
        void set(String^ value);
    }
}
```

In the .cpp file:

```
String^ Reader::Xml::get()
{
    return whatever;
}

void Reader::Xml::set(String^ value)
{
    whatever = value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am rewriting all my properties now.